# One Google Account Multiple Devices, is there a way to access info from device?

Tags: android, rest, google-app-engine, google-chrome-devtools

I don't know much about developing. I signed up for google cloud but then I know there is also google scripts, rest api, drive api, getusermedia... I am confused.

Basically I have 2 android phones and my computer.

All devices are using the same google account to sync data.

I am working on the computer and I don't need access to one of the android devices.

Is there a way to either...

1. Get access to the audio or video on the phone
2. To remote access the whole screen of the phone
3. to get into the phone and get more information

Do I use cloud text to speech? Drive api? Get user media? google scripts? developer tools?

Can someone please help me I have been trying for months now?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the kind of functionality you're talking about you need several pieces of code executing in different places and interacting with each-other:

- on the phone itself, some code has to be able to able to perform actions from remote triggers and/or collect and ship the necessary info/data remotely, acting as a server and offering access to it on-demand to a remote entity
- on the computer some code needs to be able to trigger actions and access the remote data/info corresponding phone
- in the cloud some code would act as either:

  - a dating service, just helping the other 2 pieces of code to meet and directly talk to each-other to complete the desired functionality in a peer-to-peer/mesh architecture/topology. Note that this is optional, it may be possible for the other 2 pieces of software to directly talk to each other using pre-configured contact information.
  - a middle-man, being actively involved in the communication between the other 2 pieces of code, in a client-server/star architecture/topology. Which could be offering some of the service functionality even when one of the devices is not online, based on sync services. For example the phone uploading photos to the cloud even when the computer is offline and the computer viewing them when the phone is offline.

The code pieces I mentioned may already be (partially) implemented as applications  running on or services of the operating system running in the respective places. For example a browser may be all that's needed to cover the piece of code running on the computer.

Picking a certain Google (or even other vendor) product/service depends on many factors, including, for example, the capabilities they offer, their cost, how well they fit the architecture, design and implementation of the end-to-end system/solution, personal experience and/or preference, etc.

Side note: solutions covering at least in part the functionality you're after may be already available. One such example could be [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid).